# Java bytecode compiler in JavaScript

Tags: java, javascript, compiler-construction, bytecode

I'm looking for a standard Java to Java bytecode compiler implemented in JavaScript.

Has anyone heard of anything that can accomplish this?

Comment: +1 for insane idea :-). Care to explain... why?

Comment: Haha thanks. For part of my dissertation I would like users to be to write Java code within a web browser. It would support my thesis if the code could be compiled within the browser also.

Comment: It could be worse. He could have asked for a JVM implemented in JavaScript.

Comment: @DNA I think he **is** asking for a JVM to be implemented in JavaScript. I think trying to find a client-side GWT compiler would be a lot easier.

Comment: I have one written in Logo ;)

Comment: There are a number of websites that allow you to enter Java source code on a website, but compilation and running is done on the server side, and the server then displays the results of the running code on the website. Search for "online Java compiler" if you're looking for something like that.

Comment: @Jesper That's what I'll probably be doing. But I wanted to make sure it couldn't be done client side first.

Comment: @Jivings In principle you could ofcourse write a Java compiler and JVM in JavaScript (it's not so that it can't be done), but that would indeed be an insane (although interesting) idea as Tomasz said, and I haven't seen anything like it yet.

Comment: As the matter of fact, there is a JVM implementation in Javascript already: [BicaVM](https://github.com/nurv/BicaVM). The project doesn't seem to be very well maintained however.

Comment: @Jesper Unfortunately I have no time for anything like that.

Comment: It's almost java, and bytecodes are not involved, but see http://processingjs.org/

Comment: @gsteff If you change that comment to an answer then I'll accept it, it's the closest I'll get and I  think that should work.

Comment: Aha, another candidate to illustrate the [Atwood's Law](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/07/the-principle-of-least-power.html) ? +1 ;o)

Comment: So what is the answer?

Answer (score 2):

There are several here: https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/wiki/List-of-languages-that-compile-to-JS

Such as j2js, bicavm, doppio...(see the java section)

Answer (score 1):

if your goal is to have users write Java in a browser and see it run, it makes.MUCH more sense to do the compiling and executing server side.  A servlet could read the code, compile it and run it, then push the output back to the browser.

unless your thesis is "Anything that can be written in JavaScript will eventually be written in JavaScript."